# How to parse weird (for me) timestamp field

Tags: java, xml, parsing, timestamp

I want to parse an xml log file, using Java. The weird thing though is that it contains timestamps like this:

```
timestamp="1313932930.025"
```

It does not really seem as a unix timestamp since at first look it's a double. Furthermore Java does not offer (to my knowledge) any contructor in the Timestamp class, that takes a Double argument.

Does anybody know what is this form and how could it be possibly parsed into a datetime human readable string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a unix timestamp with fractional seconds. Multiply it by 1000 and then it's in milliseconds which is what Java is expecting.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the dot from that string and parse it as long.